# Pull patchset from Gerrit into current branch

Tags: git, gerrit

I'm working on a local feature branch. When I push a commit to Gerrit, a *Change* is created, which other team members can checkout. If someone amends my commit and keeps the commit's *Change-Id*, a new *Patch Set* is created on Gerrit.

Now I want to get the other team members changes. I simply want that latest Patch Set from Gerrit in my current branch. I haven't made any other changes, so there is no need to merge anything.

Gerrit provides a few download links for Patch Set 2, like these *Pull*, *Cherry Pick* and *Checkout* commands:

```
git pull https://example.org/gerrit/ refs/changes/123/456789/2
```

```
git fetch https://example.org/gerrit/ refs/changes/123/456789/2 && git cherry-pick FETCH_HEAD
```

```
git fetch https://example.org/gerrit/ refs/changes/123/456789/2 && git checkout FETCH_HEAD
```

I tried them but they don't work the way I want though. The pull and cherry pick commands both results in merge errors. The checkout command checks out a detached head, from which I could create a new branch and then work on that new branch - that works but I don't really want to create a new branch for each Patch Set.

Is there a command to load the new Patch Set directly into my current branch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case you can't use "pull" or "cherry-pick" options because both will create a new commit based on your original commit.

Suppose B is your commit and C is your colleague one:

```
A --- B <= YOUR-BRANCH
 \
  \-- C
```

If you execute the "pull" command:

```
A --- B --- D <= YOUR-BRANCH
 \         /
  \-- C --/
```

If you execute the "cherry-pick" command:

```
A --- B --- D <= YOUR-BRANCH
 \
  \-- C
```

The correct is to execute "checkout" command followed by another checkout to move the branch pointer:

```
git fetch https://GERRIT-SERVER/a/REPO refs/changes/CHANGE/PATCHSET && git checkout FETCH_HEAD
git checkout -B YOUR-BRANCH
```

And you'll get this:

```
A --- B
 \
  \-- C <= YOUR-BRANCH
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on the commands in [Marcelo Ávila de Oliveira's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51746705/897024), I'm now using the following equivalent one-liner to reset the current branch to the state of a patchset:

```
git fetch https://example.org/gerrit/ refs/changes/123/456789/2 && git reset FETCH_HEAD
```